# Finding the relationship between Gradient and Hessian to improve convergence rate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, nonlinear-optimization, numerical-optimization

I ask for help from optimization experts:

Article [Finite-Time Convergence in Continuous-Time Optimization - http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/romero20b/romero20b.pdf](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v119/romero20b/romero20b.pdf) contains section *4. Second-Order Convergent Flows*, in which various options are proposed on how to relate the *Gradient* ($\nabla f(x)$) to the Hessian ($\nabla^2 f(x)$), and thereby affect the convergence of the algorithm (formulas $(27 - 30)$).

What I'm most interested in is the relationship that significantly improves the convergence rate. I experimented with the following relationship:

$\dot{x}=\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\sqrt{(\nabla f(x))^2+(\nabla^2 f(x))^2}}$

and found that there is an increase in speed only at those times when $(\nabla^2 f(x))^2<\approx 0.1$

For this, I introduced an additional scaling factor $\frac{1}{k}$ (where $k>>1$):

$\dot{x}=\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\sqrt{(\nabla f(x))^2+\frac{1}{k}(\nabla^2 f(x))^2}}$

But I don't like the need to manually adjust the ratio. What other (**more simple and not including inverse Hessian**) ways are there to improve the convergence rate by linking the gradient and the Hessian?

I would be glad for advice and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, either I misunderstand you or the term $(\nabla^2f(x))^2$ makes no sense in the context. It is a matrix quantity, not scalar.

Similarly with $(\nabla f(x))^2$. The square of a vector is not defined.

Maybe you mean $\|\nabla^2 f(x)\|^2$ and $\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$ ?

Secondly, to resolve the $k$ parameter issue, you can use some kind of [softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function.

A typical choice would be $$\frac{\exp(-{a_i}^k/\sigma^k)}{\displaystyle\sum_{\forall j} \exp(-{a_j}^k/\sigma^k)}$$

Where $$a_1 = (\nabla f(x))^2\\a_2 = (\nabla^2f(x))^2$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am considering one-dimensional optimization. I do not quite understand, does softmax replace $k$?

Comment: @dtn one dimensional optimization... but why would you use gradients and Hessians then? Softmax can be used if $a_j$ are values and you want a value that will vary smoothly, be bounded on $[0,1]$ and depending on how large $a_i$ is compared to all the other $a_j$s.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246166/tuning-the-optimal-control-synthesized-according-to-the-pontryagin-maximum-minim i work with gradient continuous ode

Comment: in such systems, everything depends on the measurement of the Gradient, and to increase the convergence rate, a Hessian is needed, which can also be measured in real time. such systems are used in reality (for example, when heating metal billets before rolling). softmax can also be used in the future. I have a request for you, could you show me what continuous optimization would look like using this function (softmax), i.e. we need to write the equation in the form: $\dot{x}=F(\nabla f(x),\nabla^2 f(x)) \cdot \nabla f(x)$

Comment: assumption: the function $f(x)$ is known (for example $f(x)=-x^2$, Gradient and Hessian we can calculate.

Comment: @dtn okay then it is basically first and second order differentials w.r.t. time variable?

Comment: in the case of this system, yes

Comment: I think I found something interesting. We need to dig in the direction of gradient flows. Here is one of the works arxiv.org/abs/1912.09276. Are you familiar with this topic (gradient flows, Nesterov flow), etc.?